# Thymeleaf dynamic form action does not work

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am loading the `home.html` page by setting the following model attributes:

```
@GetMapping("/")
private String getHomePage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("allUsers", this.userService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("queryResult", "");
    model.addAttribute("errors", new ArrayList<>());
    return "home";
}
```

and here is my form for updating a user's data:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/{username}(username=${user.username})}" th:object="${user}" th:method="put">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <select th:field="*{username}" id="username">
        <option th:each="singleUser : ${allUsers}" th:value="${singleUser.username}" th:text="${singleUser.username}"></option>
    </select>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" id="password" >
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></span>

    <label for="status">Status</label>
    <select th:field="*{status}" id="status">
        <option th:value="'Activated'" th:text="Activated"></option>
        <option th:value="'Deactivated'" th:text="Deactivated"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">UPDATE DATA</button>
</form>
```

When I try to submit this form, it does not bind the `username` to the URL.
instead of having `/user/whateverUsername` I have only `/user`. 
**I need to bind** the value of this select element:

```
<select th:field="*{username}" id="username">
        <option th:each="singleUser : ${allUsers}" th:value="${singleUser.username}" th:text="${singleUser.username}"></option>
</select>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't with just Thymeleaf.  This just isn't the way that html works, if you want something like this you'll have to do it yourself with JavaScript.